# C# - How to tail a file continuously via SSH

Tags: c#, linux, ssh

I have a linux host that I SSH into. How can I run the below command on my C# application and keep receiving the output?

```
tail -f -n +1 /home/username/log/mylog.log
```

My goal is to read the log from its first line and continue to keep reading it as it grows.

I have used WinSCP in the past for running SSH commands but I do not believe it supports what I'm trying to do this time around by continuing to receive output.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably do it with a `FileStream` and a `StreamReader`:

```
const string logFileName = "/home/username/log/mylog.log";

using FileStream fs = new(logFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
using StreamReader sr = new(fs);
using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();
Console.CancelKeyPress += OnCancelKeyPress;
var token = cts.Token;

try {
    while (true) {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream) {
            ProcessContent(await sr.ReadToEndAsync(token));
        }

        while (sr.EndOfStream) {
            await Task.Delay(100, token);
        }
    }
} catch (OperationCanceledException) {
    Console.WriteLine("Cancelled. Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void ProcessContent(string? line) => Console.Write(line);

void OnCancelKeyPress(object? sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) {
    cts.Cancel();
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Note: I have just done everything up to the `ProcessContent` function. Handling linebreaks to make a "tail" view where you only see the last few lines is up to you (if you actually need that at all).